# I need to filter the data based on some criteria from form page in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

The form fields are
code
name
gender
active which is boolean yes or no

and a search button to display filtered data in the table below

when we click on the search button it goes to the controller and needs to display the data on the same page of search page

so how to do it with criteria and predicates

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Data you could define the query using a criteria on the entity. Then add a custom repository method to reference that query. You can provide the parameters you care about in the interface method definition.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_entity") 
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "queryName", query = "SELECT t FROM some_entity t WHERE t.someProperty = ?1") })
public class SomeEntity {
    private Object someProperty;
    ...
}

 
@Repository
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Object>     
{
    @Query(name="queryName")
    Collection<SomeEntity> findRelatedByCustomer(Object somePropertyValue);
}
```

Read more here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories